# Wrapping C++ Standard library with Cython in ipython

Tags: python, c++, cython

According to the Cython documentation ,I write the following cython code as follows:

```
In [1]:%load_ext Cython
In [2]: %%cython
         from libcpp.vector cimport vector
​         cdef vector[int] *vec_int = new vector[int](10)
```

After compiling,the ipython generated the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------ 
... 
from libcpp.vector cimport vector 
cdef vector[int] *vec_int = new vector[int](10) 
                               ^ 
------------------------------------------------------------
/Users/m/.ipython/cython/_cython_magic_a72abb419ccf1b31db9a1851b522a4bf.pyx:3:32: Operation only allowed in c++
```

what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell `cython` that you are compiling `C++` and not `C`, through the special comment

```
# distutils: language = c++
```

adding this after the `%%cython` block will fix your problem.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to @romeric's answer, the [documentation for ipython Cython magic](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiling-with-a-jupyter-notebook) suggests using

```
%%cython --cplus
```

to turn on C++ mode. Help for the command can also be accessed by running `%%cython?` in the IPython console.

Personally I think there's a lot to be said for using the distutils comment approach, since it links the language with the code that requires it.